# cannot authenticate with twitter using dotnetopenauth

Tags: twitter, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

Hi I am trying to give users of my site the ability to login with twitter. I would like to register my app with localhost so that I can test. Due to twitter not accepting this I changed the url to 127.0.0.1 I also tried adding the portnumber. I entered my secrets in the AuthConfig File. When I click on the twitter button I get the error

`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

I then began to run my app on iis to fix a problem that my site couldn't login with my windows live account (that sorted that problem) but I still get this Unauthorized error. Someone please help.

Thank you

Comment: I have nothing to do with this project, but it looks like a nice little alternative to DotNetOpenAuth ([WorldDomination.Web.Authentication](https://github.com/PureKrome/WorldDomination.Web.Authentication))

Comment: Also, for an answer to your question, we'll need to `seez teh codez`.

Comment: THere is'nt any code...well 2 lines in the auth config  OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and couldn't solve it with `DotNetOpenAuth` no matter what I tried. The authentication process for Twitter is far more difficult to get right than either Facebook or Google+ when using `DotNetOpenAuth` as it comes. After many frustrating hours, encrypting and encoding various parts of the data varying numbers of times and always getting the unhelpful 401 unauthorised, I added [Tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) into the mix and created my own `IAuthenticationClient` for Twitter authentication. It's fairly simple to perform the authentication with `Tweetsharp`. It becomes a relatively trivial matter of this:

In your `TwitterClient` constructor:

```
var twitterService = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
```

In your implementation of `IAuthenticationClient`:

```
public void RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
{
    var requestToken = twitterService.GetRequestToken(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);
    var redirectUrl = twitterService.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken).AbsoluteUri;
    context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
}

public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context)
{
    var oAuthToken = context.Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];
    var oAuthVerifier = context.Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];
    var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oAuthToken };
    var accessToken = twitterService.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oAuthVerifier);
    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
    var user = twitterService.VerifyCredentials();
    var userId = user.Id.ToString();
    var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"accesstoken", accessToken.Token},
        {"accesstokensecret", accessToken.TokenSecret},
        {"id", userId},
        {"name", user.Name},
        {"username", user.ScreenName},
        {"link", user.Url},
    };
    return new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, userId, user.ScreenName, extraData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi It turns out that it is a config issue. I needed to specify a callback url. I set it to the same as my website

Comment: could you share your code please? I am specifying callback url and still getting {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

Comment: @leen3o Hi I have no code to share its the standard stuff that you get when you create the mvc project. I suggest you update your references uses nuget that help me when I first slamed into a wall